# How to get dig without bind

Tags: debian, bind, dig

Is there a way of installing `dig` or `nslookup` without BIND (preferably without compilation)? BIND is known to be a huge security hole, and all I need is the ability to resolve domain names to their A record IP address, so I can doublecheck that all my domain names are resolving to their correct IP address. Simple alternatives are acceptable too, as long as they can run and pipe in a shell script. This is for Debian 9.

Answer (score 4):

You can install the `dnsutils` package containing `dig` or `nslookup`, and leave alone the `bind9` package containing the BIND daemon which you do not need. (Thanks to @telcoM for adding this info  in a comment.)

In general, when all utilities come in the same package, you can simply choose not to enable the service if you don't need it. Except extraordinary cases, all vulnerabilities of a service rely on exploits against a **running** daemon, not against binaries who just sit there.

Comment: Doesn't the BIND daemon get enabled automatically? I'm afraid if I install it and then disable it, that it may cause problems later on through entanglement, or even get instantiated automatically by some other process. I've been doing this too long to blindly trust system devs. BIND has a long history of screw-ups.

Comment: The package that contains both `dig` and `nslookup` in Debian 9 is named `dnsutils`. It depends on package named `bind9-host`, but that is **not** the BIND daemon - it's just the `host` command-line tool from the BIND source distribution, because some of the utilities in `dnsutils` need it to work. The daemon package is named simply `bind9`, and you can certainly avoid installing it.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for your help and explanations :)

Comment: I'd give you all up-votes, but I'm a long-time-listener/first-time-caller, so apparently I'm lacking sufficient 'reputation' for doing so :-\ ... hey, if I get some rep, I could double-back here later and thumbs-up you then :)

Comment: I've corrected my answer to add this info. And upvoted @telcoM's comment on your behalf. :)

Comment: @RJHiggs You can always accept answers to your own questions, regardless of your reputation.

Comment: +1.  also worth mentioning is that the `host` command in `bind9-host` is often more useful for scripting purposes than either `dig` or `nslookup` - terse output, easy to extract just the data you need (like the IP address).   `dig` is more useful if you're investigating DNS-related problems.

Comment: And `nslookup` is deprecated anyway.